# Unity 3d edit (change) main model with code

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to edit my model, when player buy something from the store.
How can i do that with code?

for example

```
if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Money")>500)
{
// buy rocket for space ship... (i have space ship model with rockets)
}
```

Comment: This question is far too simple, what it is that you can't do, just turn the model on or instantiate it

Comment: It would be far easier to instantiate a new model of a rocket (or launcher for rocket) to a position on your model rather than altering your model on the fly. Alternatively, use your `ship model with rockets` and set your rockets to visible when they are purchased. (this will not work if your rockets are not their own entity on the model)

Comment: @DarceVader thanks for answers, but i'm wondering that does visible objects make game slow? (they are visible but stay in the ram still)

and one thing else, should i do that with playerprefs?

 if (player.prefs("rocketsStatu"))
// rockets are seems

Comment: @Horothenic i did'nt understand your answer :(

Comment: I don't fully understand your questions, but the rendering of an object and loading objects take the most amount of resources, why some games have large load times. PlayerPrefs should be for player preferences, [Best Practices for Saving](https://forum.unity.com/threads/basic-practices-for-saving-in-unity.223327/).

Comment: I assume you have two ships, you can unload your `ship without rockets` and instantiate your `ship with rockets`. From where it sounds like you're to in your development stage, I don't think you need to worry about ram just yet.

Comment: Thanks for all answer!

I made it with your advice! @DarceVader

Answer (score 0):

Try 
player.sprite = rocketSprite;